# How can I get the source branch for a pull request when Bamboo triggers on merge

Tags: variables, build, branch, pull-request, bamboo

Bamboo 8.11 only passes these variables when a pull request is open:

```
bamboo.repository.pr.key
bamboo.repository.pr.sourceBranch
bamboo.repository.pr.targetBranch
```

I need the sourceBranch variable for creating a git tag.

I have a Bamboo build that is triggered when pull requests are merged to master. The sourceBranch variable is not available for use at this point.

I can create a plan branch for pull requests that captures the value from these variables.

How can I propogate the sourceBranch variable from the plan branch to the main build plan that is triggered when pull requests are merged to master?

Tried writing out the the sourceBranch to file for later injection but don't know how to link plan branch build with main branch build